# remove subdirectory from url, keep root accessible

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I just want to remove the subdirectory from the URL but I still want the root directory to be accessible and even fetch the index.php from root when I go directly to the page.

I am currently using the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com$
RewriteRule !^backup/ /backup%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

But this treats the subdirectory like its root.

Thanks

Comment: For a URL like `/abc.php`: Should it be handled by `/backup/abc.php` OR just `/abc.php`?

Comment: I find it unclear what problem you are facing. Could you give some example url's that the user enters in their browser (or click on a link for that matter), what file you want to be loaded and what url should appear in the url bar?